# Dividing a negative number MASM

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, irvine32

I've written a program that's sums a bunch of numbers from the user and returns the average, but the program gets stuck when I try to divide negative numbers.  I was under the impression dividing a negative number was allowed, so I'm not sure what the problem is here.

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

; Constants
min             =       -100
max             =       -1
one             =       1

.data
num             DWORD   ?
nums            DWORD   ?
nums_message    BYTE    "Total numbers: ",0
sum             DWORD   ?
sum_message     BYTE    "Sum: ",0
average         DWORD   ?
average_message BYTE    "Average: ",0
current_loop    DWORD   ?
spaces          BYTE    "     ",0
invalid_msg     BYTE    "Out of range, Number must be between [-100...-1]",0
temp            DWORD   ?

.code
main proc

    ; Enter numbers to be displayed
    mov     ecx, 0
    enter_num:
    mov     edx, OFFSET prompt_2
    call    WriteString
    call    ReadInt
    mov     num, eax

    ; Check if non-negative
    mov     eax, num
    mov     ebx, 0
    cmp     eax, ebx
    jge     average_nums
    inc     ecx

    ; Validate user input
    validation_1:
        mov     eax, num
        mov     ebx, min
        cmp     eax, ebx
        jge     validation_2

    ; If validation fails
    invalid:
        mov     edx, OFFSET invalid_msg
        call    WriteString
        call    CrLf
        jmp     enter_num

    validation_2:
        mov     eax, num
        mov     ebx, max
        cmp     eax, ebx
        jg      invalid

    ; Sum the numbers
    sum_nums:
        mov     eax, sum
        add     eax, num
        mov     sum, eax
        jmp     enter_num

    ; Calculate the average
    average_nums:
        ; Display total numbers
        mov     edx, OFFSET nums_message
        call    WriteString
        mov     eax, ecx
        call    WriteInt
        call    CrLf

        ; Display sum
        mov     edx, OFFSET sum_message
        call    WriteString
        mov     eax, sum
        call    WriteInt
        call    CrLf

        ; Display Average
        mov     edx, OFFSET average_message
        call    WriteString
        cdq
        mov     eax, sum
        mov     ebx, nums
        div     ebx
        call    WriteInt
        call    CrLf

    exit; ; Exit to operating system
main endp

; Insert additional procedures

end main
```

Comment: Maybe use [IDIV](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_137.html) for signed division?

Comment: And if you do use `CDQ` for sign extension along with `IDIV` remember to do `CDQ` **after** you place a value in _EAX_ otherwise you are potentially doing sign extension with garbage in _EAX_.

Comment: @Michael Petch I've tried using IDIV, but the same problem persists. Even with using CDQ after setting EAX.

Comment: Step through in a debugger. Are you sure you are dividing the numbers you think you are?

Comment: Im printing the two numbers I'm diving to the screen right before trying to divide them, and they appear to be correct.

Comment: For instance I see `mov     ebx, nums` before the IDIV (well in your code DIV) but I don't see where you increment that - isn't `nums` the number of numbers. I don't see how the code you posted could possibly give you correct numbers before the division. So it appears like division by zero since nums is always 0 (and you move it to EBX)

Comment: You're right, I was accidentally using `nums` instead of the ECX register, the division works now, but it prints out a number like 2 million...

Comment: I put a breakpoint right before `div  ECX`, and the registers are EAX = FFFFFFFB, EBX = 00000000, ECX = 00000001.  I'm not sure how this is possible (or if I'm doing something wrong while debugging).  I'm printing the values out directly before the division piece of the code and the values are correct.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109493/discussion-between-123-and-michael-petch).